# How to update to the latest version of Ubuntu (12.10)

Tags: installation

I am attempting to update my computer's operating system with ubuntu 12.10.  How do I update my operating system to ubuntu 12.10 when I am already using 12.04? How can I create a disc onto which to load ubuntu 12.10 O/S from the ubuntu 12.04 O/S?

Comment: Since your actual question does not appear to have anything to do with Windows, I removed that from your subject.

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating from 12.04, you can simply update through the update manager. Since 12.04 is a LTS release (Long Term Support), you will first need to go to the window Software Sources and in the last option of the third tab (Updates) state that you are interested in being informed of every new release of Ubuntu (first option in the drop-down list). You will need to enter your code.

Now you can close the window, open the software updater and it will tell you that Ubuntu 12.10 is available.

Another option is to burn it to a disc or make a USB for booting by downloading the image from www.ubuntu.com and use either Brasero for burning CD's or the USB creator application to make a start-up USB, which you can boot from upon system start-up.

I'm a bit confused by the title of your question. Are you using Windows or Ubuntu already?

Answer (score -1):

there are two option

**1- update by using Terminal**

```
>sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
>sudo do-release-upgrade
```

**2 - update by using update-manager**

2.1 open update-manager

2.2 click Settings in the Update Manger

2.3 then select Normal Releases from the Release Upgrade menu.

2.4 check for upgrades again, and you’ll be notified that Ubuntu 12.10 is available for   upgrade.

2.5 Click the Upgrade button to get started.

[click here to watch my video that show you how to update Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMix90TZMDg)

Comment: -1 The actual commands are syntax errors.  `apt-get upgrade` will not upgrade to a new release; it will simply upgrade existing packages to their newest version if there are pending security updates for the release you are already running.  The proper command line is `sudo update-manager --dist-upgrade`